# Compiling C with non standard header

Tags: c, gcc

I have my main C file:

```
#if defined(WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#endif
#if defined(LINUX)
#include <curses.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#if defined(WIN32)
#include <conio.h>
#endif
#include <ctype.h>
#include <a429usbnt.h>

#if defined(WIN32)
#include "genlib.h"
#endif

void main()
{
    _open_xpc(1);
}
```

When I try to compile using this command

```
gcc -I. -L. test.c -o test
```

I get the following error: **undefined reference to '_open_xpc'**.

However if I change the call to the _open_xpc function and instead just

```
printf("%d", XPC_ERROR_ACTIONCODE);
```

the program compiles fine and the correct value assigned to the definition of **XPC_ERROR_ACTIONCODE** is printed out, so the compiler is linking **a429usbnt.h** but will only recognize defined variables and not the functions.

Comment: "Compiler is linking a429usbnt.h": The compiler is _including_ the header, the _linker_ needs to be told where the already-compiled definition is.

Comment: I believe that is what the -L. flag is doing? I have a .lib file that contains the definitions in the same directory as everything else. I've never compiled manually before so please forgive me if I am being dense :D

Comment: I don't know whether gcc can link .lib files. Those are usually created by Microsoft compilers.

Comment: http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.htm

Comment: Thanks Lundin, turns out I needed to use a combination of -L and -l !

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to link against a .lib file with gcc, it seems you need to define a directory with -L and an actual file with -l